# How would we measure the non-randomness and compactness of this cubic lattice and corresponding graph?

Tags: general-topology, biology

The genetic code is decrypted into a 4x4x4 cubic lattice shown here:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/361073909_Decryption_and_Topology_of_the_Genetic_Code

[image: lattice]

That cube was used to construct an un-direction graph with 21 nodes and 148 edges in Mathematica - displayed below:

[image: graph]

Comment: Closed loops: <|w -> 0, x -> 2, c -> 1, y -> 1, s -> 4, l -> 6, f -> 1, r -> 6, q -> 1, h -> 1, p -> 3, k -> 3, n -> 1, t -> 3, m -> 0, i -> 2, g -> 3, e -> 1, d -> 1, a -> 3, v -> 3|>

Comment: New analysis requiring no decryption key: Of the 12 isotropic cubes (and mirrors), GACU scores highest with 44 closed-loops.

Answer (score 0):

Designated Cube 1, the order: g, a, c, u yields a structure with the most closed-loops. The mirror of this cube (u, c, a, g) is a second solution.

(21) (PDF) Graph Analysis of the Genetic Code Using Closed-Loops Shows Isotropic Axes Using the Order GACU Yields Maximum Topological Compactness. Available from: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/361250677_Graph_Analysis_of_the_Genetic_Code_Using_Closed-Loops_Shows_Isotropic_Axes_Using_the_Order_GACU_Yields_Maximum_Topological_Compactness [accessed Jun 14 2022].
[Computational proof, but someone should try group theory:](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/361250677_Graph_Analysis_of_the_Genetic_Code_Using_Closed-Loops_Shows_Isotropic_Axes_Using_the_Order_GACU_Yields_Maximum_Topological_Compactness)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).